# Trouble implementing database into android project

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've been following [This](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842) guide for implementing a database in an android project.

This is the code for my DBAdapter class:

```
package com.sab.namespace;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PROPERTYID = "propertyid";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "propertyaddress";
    public static final String KEY_JOBNO = "jobnumber";  
    public static final String KEY_ASSIGNED = "assignedto";
    public static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "datecreated";
    public static final String KEY_MASTERKEY = "usemasterkey"; 
    public static final String KEY_PHONEBEFORE = "phonebefore";
    public static final String KEY_PROBLEM = "descriptionofproblem";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SABDatabase";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "jobs";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table jobs (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "propertyid text not null, propertyaddress text not null, "
        + "jobnumber text not null, assignedto text not null, "
        + "company text not null, datecreated text not null, "
        + "usemasterkey text not null, phonebefore text not null, "
        + "descriptionofproblem text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                              int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                  + " to "
                  + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    } 

  //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }


    //---insert a job into the database---
    public long insertJob(String propertyid, String propertyaddress, String jobnumber,
            String assignedto, String company, String datecreated, String usemasterkey,
            String phonebefore, String descriptionofproblem) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_PROPERTYID, propertyid);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, propertyaddress);
        initialValues.put(KEY_JOBNO, jobnumber);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ASSIGNED, assignedto);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, datecreated);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MASTERKEY, usemasterkey);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONEBEFORE, phonebefore);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PROBLEM, descriptionofproblem);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular job---
    public boolean deleteJob(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the jobs---
    public Cursor getAllJobs() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_PROPERTYID,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_JOBNO,
                KEY_ASSIGNED,
                KEY_COMPANY,
                KEY_DATE,
                KEY_MASTERKEY,
                KEY_PHONEBEFORE,
                KEY_PROBLEM}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }


    //---retrieves a particular job---
    public Cursor getJob(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID, 
                        KEY_PROPERTYID,
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_JOBNO,
                        KEY_ASSIGNED,
                        KEY_COMPANY,
                        KEY_DATE,
                        KEY_MASTERKEY,
                        KEY_PHONEBEFORE,
                        KEY_PROBLEM}, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a job---
    public boolean updateJob(long rowId, String propertyid, String propertyaddress, String jobnumber,
            String assignedto, String company, String datecreated, String usemasterkey,
            String phonebefore, String descriptionofproblem)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_PROPERTYID, propertyid);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, propertyaddress);
        args.put(KEY_JOBNO, jobnumber);
        args.put(KEY_ASSIGNED, assignedto);
        args.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
        args.put(KEY_DATE, datecreated);
        args.put(KEY_MASTERKEY, usemasterkey);
        args.put(KEY_PHONEBEFORE, phonebefore);
        args.put(KEY_PROBLEM, descriptionofproblem);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

And then I try to use the database in my ViewJobs.java class

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();        
        long id;
        id = db.insertJob(
                "PROP121",
                "MARK ANDREWS DRIVE",
                "JOB32",
                "COLIN",
                "SAB",
                "12/4/13",
                "yes",
                "yes",
                "SHIT IS EVERYWHERE");
        id = db.insertJob(
                "PROP122",
                "FAULTY CLOSE",
                "JOB33",
                "DAVE",
                "SAB",
                "13/4/13",
                "yes",
                "yes",
                "FIX PLEASE");
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, Long.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast outputs -1 which tells me there has been an error with inputting the data but I can't find where I've gone wrong.

If I just ignore the error and continue on with the following code then my application crashes.

```
db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllJobs();
        db.close();
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could offer any advice!

-Harry

Here is the logcat code for when it crashes:

```
03-04 18:37:59.760: W/dalvikvm(2078): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-04 18:37:59.809: I/dalvikvm(2078): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sab.namespace/com.sab.namespace.ViewJobs}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: jobs: , while compiling: SELECT _id, propertyid, propertyaddress, jobnumber, assignedto, company, datecreated, usemasterkey, phonebefore, descriptionofproblem FROM jobs
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: jobs: , while compiling: SELECT _id, propertyid, propertyaddress, jobnumber, assignedto, company, datecreated, usemasterkey, phonebefore, descriptionofproblem FROM jobs
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.sab.namespace.DBAdapter.getAllJobs(DBAdapter.java:114)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.sab.namespace.ViewJobs.onCreate(ViewJobs.java:52)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-04 18:37:59.958: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     ... 11 more
03-04 18:37:59.969: I/dalvikvm(2078): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-04 18:38:00.328: I/dalvikvm(2078): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-04 18:38:00.358: I/dalvikvm(2078): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-04 18:38:00.658: I/dalvikvm(2078): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-04 18:38:00.799: I/dalvikvm(2078): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-04 18:38:03.210: I/Process(2078): Sending signal. PID: 2078 SIG: 9
```

Here is the full code for ViewJobs.java

```
package com.sab.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewJobs extends Activity {

    String titles[] = {"hello","bannana","frogshehe","hello","bannana","frogshehe","hello","bannana","frogshehe","hello","bannana","frogshehe","hello","bannana","frogshehe"};
    ListView vListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> lVAAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        //database stuff
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();        
        long id;
        id = db.insertJob(
                "PROP121",
                "MARK ANDREWS DRIVE",
                "JOB32",
                "COLIN",
                "SAB",
                "12/4/13",
                "yes",
                "yes",
                "SHIT IS EVERYWHERE");
        id = db.insertJob(
                "PROP122",
                "FAULTY CLOSE",
                "JOB33",
                "DAVE",
                "SAB",
                "13/4/13",
                "yes",
                "yes",
                "FIX PLEASE");
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, Long.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllJobs();
        db.close();
        /*
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
                DisplayJob(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        */

      //create list
        vListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vlistview);
        lVAAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewJobs.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);

        //create listener
        vListView.setAdapter(lVAAdapter);
        vListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lVAAdapter, View myView,
                    int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                    String selectedFromList = (String) (vListView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                    if (titles[myItemInt] == "hello") {
                        titles[2] = "test";
                        vListView.invalidateViews();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    public void DisplayJob(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "propertyid: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "propertyaddress: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                "jobnumber: " + c.getString(3) + "\n" +
                "assignedto: " + c.getString(4) + "\n" +
                "company: " + c.getString(5) + "\n" +
                "datecreated: " + c.getString(6) + "\n" +
                "usemasterkey: " + c.getString(7) + "\n" +
                "phonebefore: " + c.getString(8) + "\n" +
                "descriptionofproblem:  " + c.getString(9),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat on the crash.

Comment: Added the logcat code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably added the jobs table after creating the database. The onCreate would not be called. So you need to clear the data for the onCreate to be called again.

Comment: No change it seems. Still returning -1 from id and crashing when getAllJobs() is called.

Comment: Somehow your table jobs is not created at all. Does your ViewJobs class extends Activity?

Comment: Yes it does, I will also include the full code for ViewJobs if that helps.

Comment: The database is not changed with the code above, since it was installed. Either unsinstall your app or clear data and relaunch.

Comment: You should always at least have Name shadowing and conflicts options as Warning. On Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings and scroll down to Name shadowing and conflicts.

Comment: Changing an argument name doesn't make a difference; overriding or overloading is based on argument types, not argument names.

Comment: I realized that, probably because he add the jobs table after creating the database. Thus onCreate would not be called to create the table again until he cleared data. It worked for him probably because he unsintalled or cleared data as I suggested above.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with that. Your original answer might confuse others though!